# How convert Image to png with imagemagik lib in C#?

Tags: c#, .net-core, aws-lambda, imagemagick, png

I've write a aws Lambda to convert my images.

The process of the lambda function is to take input images of any format and in the case of non-png images, convert them to jpeg otherwise add some data and convert it to png by adding transparency. Finally save the generated images on s3.

I write a function in C# using a imagemagick library in .Net Core.

I've a problem with png conversion. The result image have a dashed border!

[image: Generated Image Broken]

This is my method to PNG convert.

```
private MemoryStream ConvertToPNG(MemoryStream inputStream)
        {
            MemoryStream outputStream = new MemoryStream();
            inputStream.Position = 0;
            using (MagickImage image = new MagickImage())
            {
                image.Read(inputStream);
                image.Quality = 90;
                image.TransformColorSpace(ColorProfile.SRGB, ColorProfile.AdobeRGB1998);
                image.Settings.Compression = CompressionMethod.NoCompression;
                image.Format = MagickFormat.Png64;
                image.Write(outputStream);
            }
            return outputStream;
        }
```

I tried with another stack, using Pillow library in py and work, generated image is great. Unfortunately I am forced to use C # and .Net for obvious reasons.

Has anyone ever had this problem?
Thanks everyone for the contribution.

Comment: Sorry, not understood. No standard language. Use english please.
"In my case any images (that NOT are png) to jpeg, else convert to PNG with other information that i need ."

Comment: Sorry, you're right. Haste is the enemy of calm.